# Dynamically access an imported module's methods in TypeScript

Tags: d3.js, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, typescript-generics

I'm trying to do something like this:

```js
import * as d3 from 'd3-scale-chromatic'

const selectColor = (
    decimal: number, 
    colorScheme: string = 'interpolateRainbow'
): string => 
    d3[colorScheme](decimal)
```

but I'm getting this TS error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof import("PATH_TO_MODULES/node_modules/@types/d3-scale-chromatic")'

I *think* I basically want to extend the type I'm importing with something along the lines of:

```js
interface d3 {
    [key: string]: (number) => string
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Method 1: Declare `colorScheme` as `keyof typeof d3`, cast string type to it at the call site.

```js
type D3Scale = keyof typeof d3;
const selectColor = (
    decimal: number, 
    colorScheme: D3Scale = 'interpolateRainbow'
): string => 
    d3[colorScheme](decimal);

selectColor(1,'interpolateRainbow'); // OK
let k:string = prompt("Input method name:");
selectColor(1,k as D3Scale); // need to cast
```

Method 2: Cast d3 to its index signature.

```js
type D3IndexType = {[k:string]:typeof d3[keyof typeof d3]};
const selectColor = (
    decimal: number, 
    colorScheme: string = 'interpolateRainbow'
): string => 
    (d3 as D3IndexType)[colorScheme](decimal)
```

Comment: I used method 2 in my case - worked beautifully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can play around `Conditional types` and map each colorScheme to its implementation.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types

Comment: But there is no reason to do it. If something is hard to write on typescript, you _probable_ do it wrong. I would say you are trying to merge statically typed functions to the runtime defined "selectColor" function and then again make it statically typed. You can do it using conditional types but I do not see benefits of doing extra work